# How can we add / update a image path with own code without using ->addImageToMediaGallery() , on magento

Tags: magento

Can we update a own defined product image path to database, I am adding products with own custom code.I want to add image database without help of

```
->addImageToMediaGallery()
```

Is it doable?? without using this line i want to add direct path // external url to database

```
->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ())) //media gallery initialization
->addImageToMediaGallery('xxx/my.jpg', array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento is a system which is having events and to handle those events there are observers. So my suggestion to you would be a strict no until you know which events will be triggered by  function addImageToMediaGllery() . You can do this if you know exactly which events will be triggered and you handle those events  accordingly.